# Using merge in SQL Server to update a third table

Tags: sql-server-2008

I've two tables A and B. Table A is the source and B is the target. Based on some conditions, I'll be either updating existing rows (selective columns only) in the B from A or inserting as a new row in B from A. A and B have the same columns. This I can do using MERGE.

Now, If the row in the table B is updated, I need to update some records in 3rd table C. Is it possible to do this in the following statement,

```
MERGE B
USING A
ON A.somecolumn = B.somecolumn

WHEN MATCHED THEN

UPDATE 
SET
B.somecolumn1 = A.somecolumn1,
B.somecolumn2 = A.somecolumn2

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
INSERT INTO B
somecolumn1, 
somecolumn2, 
somecolumn3,
somecolumn4 

VALUES
(
A.somecolumn1, 
A.somecolumn2, 
A.somecolumn3,
A.somecolumn4 
);
```

Answer (score 3):

This Microsoft [article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) shows an example of using `OUTPUT $action...` at the end of your query populate a temp table.  This is the approach you will have to use.

My previous idea of being able to use a `MERGE` statement as a sub query of an `UPDATE` on a third table does not work.  I could update my answer to use a temp table/variable but the answer (and example) from [@Mikael Eriksson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8337531/210496) already provide you with a clean solution, and mine would just mimic that when I was done.

Comment: I tried using output from `merge` in an update and I got. "A nested INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or MERGE statement is not allowed in the FROM clause of an UPDATE or DELETE statement." So I don't think it is possible to do this with `update`.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson My research agrees with you, it appears you cannot accomplish this without a temp table / table variable.  Thanks again.

Comment: insert into @A values (1, 1),(2, 2),(2,1)
insert into @B values (1, 0)
     With this input, I got the result @B as (1,1), (2,2) and (2,1) but I was expecting it to be (1,1),(2,1) as the 3rd data set from @ A is just the update to the 2nd set from @A. IS there any way to make the merge Code behave like I expected @ (Mikael and  Adam)?

Answer (score 3):

You need temp storage of the [output](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) from the merge statement and a update statement that use the temp table / table variable.

```
-- Your table A, B and C
declare @A table(ID int, Col int)
declare @B table(ID int, Col int)
declare @C table(ID int, Col int)

-- Sample data
insert into @A values (1, 1),(2, 2)
insert into @B values (1, 0)
insert into @C values (1, 0),(2, 0)

-- Table var to store ouput from merge
declare @T table(ID int, Col int, Act varchar(10))

-- Merge A -> B
merge @B as B
using @A as A
on A.ID = B.ID
when not matched then insert (ID, Col) values(A.ID, A.Col)
when matched then update set Col = A.Col
output inserted.ID, inserted.Col, $action into @T;

-- Update C with rows that where updated by merge    
update C set
  Col = T.Col
from @C as C
  inner join @T as T
    on C.ID = T.ID and
       T.Act = 'UPDATE'
```

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/qt/119724/

Comment: insert into @A values (1, 1),(2, 2),(2,1)
insert into @B values (1, 0)
     With this input, I got the result @B as (1,1), (2,2) and (2,1) but I was expecting it to be (1,1),(2,1) as the 3rd data set from @ A is just the update to the 2nd set from @A. IS there any way to make the merge Code behave like I expected @ (Mikael and  Adam)?

Comment: @user1072578 - Nope, that is not the way merge works. It will figure out what rows are matched and not matched before it modifies anything. What you **can** do is to group by on ID in the using clause and get the `max(col)` or `min(col)` whichever is most appropriate. Something like this: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/qt/120833/