# Using merge statement to insert / update 3rd table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have one source table and two target table where i have to use merge action to complete this.
The condition is as follow. I have acheive merging data from source table to target table 1.

However, I am having problem with updating to target table 2 based on follow conditions. Hope someone can help.

Note:
I am refering to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8337304/using-merge-in-sql-server-to-update-a-third-table) post, but this post shows updating the 2nd table without condition but I do have a condition which is based on the source table and second targeted table.

```
WHEN NOT MATCHED
  INSERT INTO target table 1
  INSERT INTO target table 2(targettable1ID, value3)
WHEN MATCHED
  IF src.value3 != target2.value3
    UPDATE targettable1 only
  ELSE 
    UPDATE targettable1 and targettable2


merge into [TargetTable1] as tgt
using (select * from [SrcTable] as src)
on tgt.SrcTableID = src.SrcTableID
when not matched then insert (Value1, Value2) values(src.Value1, src.Value2)
when matched then update set tgt.Value1 = src.Value1, tgt.Value 2 = src.Value2

[SrcTable]
SrcTableID
Value1
Value2
Value3

[TargetTable1]
TargetTable1ID
SrcTableID
Value1
Value2

[TargetTable2]
TargetTable2ID
TargetTable1ID(foreign key for targettable1)
Value3(from SrcTable Value3)
```

Comment: Don't believe this is possible.  I'd suggest two MERGE statements wrapped in a transaction.

Comment: just a thought - maybe having your inserts in a begin/end block will help

Comment: @BaconBits can you explain in detail on how to use two merge statement to achieve expected result? TargetTable1 and TargetTable2 have parent child relationship.

Comment: @Adish only delete, insert or update statement is allowed right after inside when not matched and when matched